# Old router doesn't activate

Tags: router

To solve my issue with slow/unreliable wifi due to wide concrete walls at my workplace I decided to connect a router to the wired connection they gave me and create a separate, private connection with it. I chose to use my very old DI-524, since I don't have anything else right now. I tried connecting the router to the wall outlet, but it didn't work. The "power" led activates instantly and a couple of seconds later the "WAN" led and the connections from 1 to 4 start blinking, but the status led never lights up. Other than that, the other (blinking) leds start to become faint and turn off over time. What could cause this? It feels like the power source is insufficient, but I'm not sure.

Comment: DI-524 needs power source DC 7.5V 1.5A. Check... it is very common error when one tries to use 5V power source...

Comment: If DC is ok, try to reset it. Connect DC, wait until Ready blinks (maybe ~1min). Press Reset button by any thin thing (clip, toothpick, etc.) for 10 sec, then release. Wait until Ready blinks again. Then try to attach your PC to the router and tune its settings.

Comment: @Akina The power cable is the stock one, it should output the correct amount of electricity, but thanks for the other suggestions, I'll try it the second I'm able

Comment: I'd recommend to check the DC quality by a volt-meter additionally. Because "leds start to become faint and turn off over time" may mean its voltage decreases after a few seconds of normal work... if so replace it. In practice - the router works normally with 9V/2A power source.

Comment: PSUs get 'tired' with time. Unfortunately measuring just 'how tired' is not an easy process [ref @Akina above] - as when they're not under load, they will give the correct readings. When they are under load, you can't measure it accurately without some expensive testing gear. By far the simplest 'test' is to replace the PSU.

Comment: @Akina The DC is dead, so go ahead and post an answer, and I'll accept it